# Failed to build gem native extension when installing bcrypt-ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bcrypt

When running: `gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '3.0.1'` I get the following errors:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing bcrypt-ruby:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /U/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/ext/mri
/U/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/bin/ruby -I /U/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20210824-80693-sdyma7.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /U/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/ext/mri
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /U/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/ext/mri
make "DESTDIR="
compiling bcrypt_ext.c
bcrypt_ext.c:27:19: error: implicit declaration of function 'ruby_bcrypt' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    return (VALUE)ruby_bcrypt(args->output, args->key, args->salt);
                  ^
bcrypt_ext.c:27:19: note: did you mean 'ruby_script'?
/U/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2747:6: note: 'ruby_script' declared here
void ruby_script(const char* name);
     ^
bcrypt_ext.c:42:25: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            NIL_P(input) ? 0 : RSTRING_LEN(input));
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/U/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1007:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING_EMBED_LEN(str) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/U/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1003:6: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_EMBED_LEN'
     (long)((RBASIC(str)->flags >> RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_SHIFT) & \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
bcrypt_ext.c:42:25: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
            NIL_P(input) ? 0 : RSTRING_LEN(input));
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/U/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1008:28: note: expanded from macro 'RSTRING_LEN'
     RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len)
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
make: *** [bcrypt_ext.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

My Ruby version is 2.7.2. Any ideas what to try to get it installed?

Comment: In [How To Install](https://github.com/bcrypt-ruby/bcrypt-ruby/tree/v3.0.1#how-to-install-bcrypt) for version "3.0.1" it shows only ruby versions 1.8.X and 1.9.X are supported. It looks like the latest version on rubygems is 3.1.5 maybe try that instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to add a flag when installing:

```
gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '3.0.1' -- --with-cflags=-Wno-implicit-function-declaration
```

This installed the gem successfully with Ruby 2.7.2

Comment: Also works on Mac M1, ruby 2.4.1.